# Application Config file using Kubernetes ConfigMaps

Tags: docker, kubernetes, vmware

I would like to ask, what is the preferred way or best way to pass Config file for my app under the following scenario.

My app is developed on NodeJS and i have a JSON file called "config.json" that contains all the config parameters of my application i.e. AD, SMTP, DB etc. a glimpse of the file is like.

```
{
  "slackIncomingHook": [
    {"HookUrl": "<<HookUrl>>"}
  ],
  "wikiPage": {
    "url": "<<url>>",
    "timeFrame" : "week"
  },
  "database": {
    "dbName": "DBNAME",
    "dbHostName": "mongodb://username:password@<<IP Address>>:27017/"
  }
}
```

Now i want to deploy this project using Kubernetes and i want to pass this information to at runtime or somehow merged at the time when the cluster is being built using configMaps.

My DockerFile for this project consists of copying two separate/dependent projects, setting ENV, NPM Installs and exposing PORTS.

PS - the Docker Image is pushed to my Private Repository.

Experts advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you already know about ConfigMaps; what issues are you running into?

Comment: The best practice to push my config file into the specified dir of my container and then leave no traces on the host. The problem i see with ConfigMap is that the credentials would reside in Kubernetes and anyone with Read access to configMap can see that. However i want a solution more like to provide a config file at the time of building cluster and PHEWWWW.

Comment: If the problem is to pass raw data to everyone that have access to a configmap description, you should use secret for passwords and sensitive information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either create a ConfigMap or a Secret e.g.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
  namespace: default
data:
  AppConfig.json: |-
    {
      "slackIncomingHook": [
        {"HookUrl": "<<HookUrl>>"}
      ],
      "wikiPage": {
        "url": "<<url>>",
        "timeFrame" : "week"
      },
      "database": {
        "dbName": "DBNAME",
        "dbHostName": "mongodb://username:password@<<IP Address>>:27017/"
      }
    }
```

You can create secret also as they are base64 encoded so

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
data:
  AppConfig.json: |-
     BASE_64_ENCODED_JSON
```

In the deployment, add secret/config to volumes node and set volume mounts and mountPath to the path of your config.json.

```
volumeMounts:
    - name: test-secretm
      mountPath: PATH_OF_YOUR_CONFIG_JSON

volumes:
      - name: test-secretm
        secret:
            secretName: test-secret
```